# Warning: Error in &&: 'length = 2' in coercion to 'logical(1)'

Tags: r, shiny

I am running the real application and the got the exact the same error that I am getting after running below code:
When I am click New button [image]
the following error is appeared. The same code worked before, what has changed in shiny?

```
library(shiny)
#library(DT)
library(DTedit)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  Grocery_List_Results <- dtedit(
    input, output,
    name = 'Grocery_List',
    thedata = data.frame(
      Buy = c('Tea', 'Biscuits', 'Apples'),
      Quantity = c(7, 2, 5),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  h3('Grocery List'),
  uiOutput('Grocery_List')
)


runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server), launch.browser = TRUE) 


 Warning: Error in &&: 'length = 2' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
```

version.string R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt)

It mean it is the problem of dtedit library or Rstudio or both.
I  am using `devtools::install_github('DavidPatShuiFong/DTedit@2.3.0')`
I have two option replace:
If we   install instead using   `devtools::install_github('DavidPatShuiFong/DTedit@2.2.0')`

the above small shiny app works, but in my real app it gives me another error:

`Error in dteditmod(input, output, session = name, thedata = thedata, ...) : input.types must only contain values of: dateInput, selectInput, numericInput, textInput, textAreaInput, passwordInput, selectInputMultiple, selectInputReactive, selectInputMultipleReactive, fileInput`

2. and if I will use  `devtools::install_github('jbryer/DTedit')`

`Warning: Error in DTedit::dtedit: unused arguments (input.choices.reactive = list(MerchantNameList = MerchantNameList_reac, MerchantNameListCtrl = MerchantNameListCtrl_reac), text.delete.modal = "Are you sure you want to delete this record?")`

I tried three version of  DTedit , but all of them gives me some error. Do you have some suggestion?

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljJKD.png

Comment: It works fine for me.  Perhaps you need to restart RStudio or update packages.